# Random Button Location Reeaction Game

Tags: c#, button, random, location

I am trying to create a reaction game, composed of a Windows Form, a random appearing button, and a TestBox to count the hits.

This is my code so far. When I debug it the variable "i" receives the value 9, why?!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    Random x = new Random();
    for (i = 0;  i < 10; i++)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(
            int.Parse(x.Next(400).ToString()), 
            int.Parse(x.Next(250).ToString())
            );
        button1.Location = pt;
        textBox1.Text = "Hits: " + i;


    }

}
```

I am new to C# and I googled a lot but I guess I can't find my mistake.

Comment: You want the click handler to run a method that moves the button once. (And keep the total number of moves stored in a private field or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this line.

```
textBox1.Text = "Hits: " + i;
```

You are putting above sentence in loop so when the loop stops "i" variable has value 9 which will be displayed in textbox.

Once the button clicked it moves the position of button 10 times and then puts the value of  "i" in textbox.

To make it correct make the following correction in the code.

```
int i=0; // Define i at class level
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Random x = new Random();

        i++;
        Point pt = new Point(
            int.Parse(x.Next(400).ToString()), 
            int.Parse(x.Next(250).ToString())
            );
        button1.Location = pt;
        textBox1.Text = "Hits: " + i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, how can I fix this?

Comment: Wow. Thanks SO much Nirav Kamani! You really helped me a lot! :-)